# c# Tableadapters and "The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application"

Tags: c#, postgresql, architecture, odbc, tableadapter

first of all i want to say that this problem is NOT about having selected a a x64 driver for a x86, or viceversa. Its not the odbc32 thing.

Yesterday needed to do an emergency format of this crappy windows 10. I did and started to install my programs. All fine. I prepared my visual studio comunity 2015 to continue working with my project, instalation went fine, installed postgresql odbc connector as usual. But now the project yesterday was running perfecty gives me this error.

Just to be sure its not a connector problem started a new project, added dataset, tables from server, new datagrid...all is working perfectly fine.

Back to my current project every time the code calls Tableadaper.Fill() method it returns the exception:

ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

I've tried to replace the tableadapters with new ones with no effect. Any ideas?

```
private void form_comp_consulta_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        arteconf_baseDataSet.EnforceConstraints = false;

        proveedoresTableAdapter.Fill(arteconf_baseDataSet.proveedores);  //Error comes from this line, in all formularies. Every time a TableAdapter.Fill() is used.
        componentesTableAdapter.Fill(arteconf_baseDataSet.componentes);

        this.ActiveControl = textBox_comp_consulta_buscar;

    }
```